# MySQL : weekly and monthly SUM

Tags: mysql, select

The below given is my **TOUR** table:

```
    tour_id | tour_date | amount
    ------------------------------
    ABC     | 2016-03-07   | 100
    ABC     | 2016-03-15   | 200
    DEF     | 2016-03-07   | 300
    DEF     | 2016-03-15   | 100
    GHI     | 2016-03-07   | 30
```

I want to get the following:

- sum total per week
- sum total per month.

This final data must look like this:

```
  tour_id| weekly sum. | monthly sum.
    --------------------------------
    ABC  | 100         | 300       
    DEF  | 300         | 400   
    GHI  | 30          | 30
```

Comment: What is the difference between `current month total` and `sum total per month` ?

Comment: _Which_ month is the current month?  A year has 12 months.

Comment: Wich week you should see? There are 53...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    SELECT 
    tour_id, WEEKLY, MONTHLY
FROM
    TOUR T1
        INNER JOIN
    (SELECT 
        tour_id, SUM(amount) WEEKLY
    FROM
        TOUR
    GROUP BY tour_id , WEEK(tour_date)) WEEK ON WEEK.tour_id = T1.tour_id
        INNER JOIN
    (SELECT 
        tour_id, SUM(amount) MONTHLY
    FROM
        TOUR
    GROUP BY tour_id , DATE_FORMAT(tour_date, '%m')) MONTH ON WEEK.tour_id = MONTH.tour_id
```

Try above query.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT WEEK.*
     , MONTH.MONTHLY
FROM (SELECT tour_id
     , WEEK(tour_date) week
     , YEAR(tour_date) year
     , SUM(amount) WEEKLY
     FROM TOUR
     GROUP BY tour_id , WEEK(tour_date), YEAR(tour_date)) WEEK 
INNER JOIN (SELECT tour_id
                 , YEAR(tour_date) year
                 , MONTH(tour_date) month
                 , SUM(amount) MONTHLY
            FROM TOUR
            GROUP BY tour_id , MONTH(tour_date), YEAR(tour_date)) MONTH ON WEEK.tour_id = MONTH.tour_id AND WEEK.year = MONTH.year
```